# Center elements in GridView

Tags: android, gridview

I have GridView with 6 images in 2 columns. I want to display this 6 images in the middle of the screen. I set gravity properties to center but this center elements only horizontally. GridView takes whole screen.

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_above="@id/ad" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:numColumns="2"    
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"       
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

Answer (score 55):

Here is what I did to get the items in the gridview to center (notice the stretchmode, columnwidth, gravity and horizontal and vertical spacing):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

It took me a while to figure it out, but messing with those different values I was able to get them to center.

Comment: for me `HorizontalSpacing` caused some issues with `spacingWidthUnfirom` but was fine after i removed it

Comment: I found that android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" did it for me

Comment: @T0m can you let us know which tag you put that on?

Comment: It was the GridView tag

Comment: Yeap, I think `android:horizontalSpacing="10dp" ` did the job for me!

Answer (score 13):

Try wrapping your GridView in a LinearLayout that has it's child elements centered and change your gridview's layout_height to "wrap_content". ex:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:gravity="center"
  android:layout_gravity="center">
    <GridView 
      android:id="@+id/homeGridView"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:numColumns="3"
      android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
      android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
      android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
      android:gravity="center" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: out of all I could find on SO, this was the only answer that worked for me

Answer (score 9):

Need to set the following attributes:

```
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
```

...and...

```
android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 5):

well, in case you are using a custom adapter thing to inflate single rowview inside your gridview then try to add **android:gravity="center"** to the layout of your single_row.. this will do the trick hopefully :)
i.e,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivClrBlock"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="88dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvClrName"
        android:layout_width="88dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/color_name"
        android:textSize="15sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue occurred when I updated the gridview adapter from:

```
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mobile, null);
```

to

```
        gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mobile, parent, false);
```

so I just reversed back using a try catch if the old (null) version failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:
`android:layout_height="fill_parent"`
into
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

You are now telling your grid view to fill it's parent height and width fully.

Comment: Thank you. I tried this way but this not solve the problem, elements don't center vertically inside GridView.

Comment: I'm little confused but I'll try to help. Have you tried to set the GridView parent to center all its elements? Also you could try to change the gravity attribute to something else and see if that helps. Here is the link to possible attributes http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html#attr_android:gravity

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnWidth="100dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Don't use `padding` or `horizontalSpacing` if you don't need it as it may cause problems with other views.

Note also that `fill_parent` is already deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will solve your problem:

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/gridlayou4x3"
        android:rowCount="4"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that you just have the `gridlayout` wrap content on `height` and `width`.

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

It will center itself for the size it needs but if you have it matching the parent. You are technically centering it based with a lot of parent empty space offsetting your children.