# Center-align items in Gridview

Tags: android, gridview

I'm making a game on Android Studio and have an issue with Grid View component. I can't align center the items inside Grid View like [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwOTM.png) image. I try several ways like `android:stretchMode` or `android:layout_centerHorizontal` but it doesn't help. Here is my XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <GridView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="10px"
            android:id="@+id/gridAnswersChar"
            android:numColumns="8"
            android:gravity="center">
        </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Did you check this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816004/center-elements-in-gridview

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Center elements in GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4816004/center-elements-in-gridview)

Answer (score 16):

Hopefully it is not a strict requirement for you that you use `GridView`, as I believe what you're looking for is essentially impossible. However, if you're willing to use `RecyclerView` instead, I have a solution for you.

This solution will make use of `FlexboxLayoutManager`, a part of Google's **FlexboxLayout** project: https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Full code for my solution is visible here:
https://gist.github.com/zizibaloob/0c44bfe59b371b5ae0bd2edcb4a7e592

I'll cover the important bits here. First, the setup of `FlexboxLayoutManager` in `MainActivity.onCreate()`:

```
FlexboxLayoutManager manager = new FlexboxLayoutManager(this, FlexDirection.ROW);
manager.setJustifyContent(JustifyContent.CENTER);

RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
recycler.setLayoutManager(manager);
```

When we create the layout manager, we pass `FlexDirection.ROW` to tell it we want it to lay our items out horizontally (i.e. fill up a row and then flow to the next row, rather than filling up a column and then flowing to the next column).

We then call `setJustifyContent()` using `JustifyContent.CENTER` to tell the manager that we want partially-filled rows to be centered.

The second important bit is the way in which we mimic the behavior of `GridView` and its ability to have a set number of columns. This code is in `MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder()`:

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layoutParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) itemView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.width = (parent.getWidth() / 4) - layoutParams.leftMargin - layoutParams.rightMargin;
itemView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

The key here is `(parent.getWidth() / 4)`, which gives each item view one quarter of the available width. If you want a different number of columns, simply change the `4` to an `8`, etc.

We also subtract `leftMargin` and `rightMargin` from the width because our item views have margin, and we need to leave space for them. If your views won't have margins, you can skip this.

Put it all together and you get an app that looks like this:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Easy and better way to align images and content in centre is use gravity as centre in your item_layout file, not in parent of your grid-view.

Comment: Sure this will center the content inside the item, but will not center the the last  or odd items in grid view.  @BenP answer shows the solution you cannot achieve with gravity alone.

Comment: Also add textview width to match parent and textAlignment attribute to centre.